# Proving $(A\cap\bar{B})\cup(\bar{A}\cap B) = \varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Proving $(A\cap\bar{B})\cup(\bar{A}\cap B) = \varnothing$

I tried to prove this statement. And I came up with confusion. And I doubt whether this statement is correct or not.
Could somebody help me solve this one?

Comment: It is incorrect.  Can you try an example?  In fact, you should find that $(A\cap \overline{B})\cup (\overline{A}\cap B)=\emptyset$ if and only if $A=B$ which is not true most of the time.

Comment: Only use [Proof-Explanation] as a tag if you have a proof of someone else's that you want explained.  You don't have someone else's proof present.  Only use [Solution-Verification] as a tag if you have your own *complete* attempt that you want verified for correctness.  You don't have your own attempt present.  Don't use the [Proof-Writing] tag unless the question is about the *generics* of writing proofs in general (*for example, questions about why induction works as a proof technique, etc...*).  Your question is not one of these, it is a question about a specific example.

Comment: I am new to this platform. By the way, thank you for the suggestion. Next time I will try to match these conditions.

Comment: Are you familiar with Venn diagrams?

Comment: Since as @JMoravitz notes the statement isn't always true, maybe instead of *proving* it you're meant to *solve* it.

Comment: Can you define what $\bar{A}$ means? (I have a nagging suspicion your tags are incorrect still)

Comment: I agree with @BrianMoehring . Some people use $\overline A$ to mean the complement of $A$, and some use it to mean the closure of $A$. In neither case is the statement you want provable, but the explanation will be quite different in the two cases.

Comment: $\bar{A}$  means the complement of A.
And I am familiar with the Venn diagram.